# Make multiple folders from excel using AppleScript with specific naming structure

Tags: applescript, directory

I need to make thousands of folders from columns from excel. I've looked around the internet and have got close, but I need the naming structure to be

"LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME - ID"

Each of those are in a separate column in excel. 
I've tried the code below and it works, but the naming structure is not what I want it to be.

```
display dialog " --Make Lotsa' Folders-- 
This AppleScript will create multiple folders using names from a text file that you specify."
set destination to (choose folder with prompt "Where would you like to make the folders?")
set textFile to (choose file with prompt "Select the text file you wish to use")
set folderNames to paragraphs of (read textFile)
repeat with oneName in folderNames
tell application "Finder" to make new folder at destination with properties {name:oneName}
end repeat
display dialog "Your folders are done." buttons {"OK"}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye27E.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3UCi.jpg This is what the folder filename would be.

Comment: Please add an example of the excel structure

Comment: I don't have 10 rep points to post the image... But I added a link to a pic of it.

Comment: IMO The fastest and easiest way to get this done, not using AppleScript, is to save the Excel document as a tab delimitated unquoted plain text file, e.g. filename.csv and then in Terminal `cd` to the target directory you want the folders created in, then use the following _command_: `while read -r line; do mkdir "$(awk '{print $1 ", " $2 " - " $3}'<<<"$line")"; done < /path/to/filename.csv`

Comment: You might find this interesting.... Using a 10,000 line CSV file in `bash` it took 1 minute to create all 10,000 folders with the naming convention you wanted. Using the same file in Excel and the AppleScript answer by vadian (which does work and is a good AppleScript answer) it took 4 minutes to just create the first 1,000, meaning it would take ~40 minutes in AppleScript to do what was done in 1 minute in `bash`. While what you want to achieve in AppleScript is doable, nonetheless I would do it in `bash`!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
set destination to (choose folder with prompt "Where would you like to make the folders?")
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set usedRange to string value of used range of sheet 1

repeat with i from 2 to (count usedRange)
    tell item i of usedRange to set folderName to item 1 & ", " & item 2 & " - " & item 3
    tell application "Finder" to make new folder at destination with properties {name:folderName}
end repeat
display dialog "Your folders are done." buttons {"OK"}
```

As mentioned in the comments the Finder is very very slow while creating the folders one by one, this is a faster solution keeping the way to parse Excel (which is pretty fast by the way) but using the shell `mkdir` command with a composed parameter list to create the folders.

```
set destination to (choose folder with prompt "Where would you like to make the folders?")
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set usedRange to string value of used range of sheet 1

set nameList to {}
repeat with i from 2 to (count usedRange)
    tell item i of usedRange to set end of nameList to "'" & item 1 & ", " & item 2 & " - " & item 3 & "'"
end repeat
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ","}
set mkdirParams to "/{" & (nameList as text) & "}"
set text item delimiters to TID
do shell script "/bin/mkdir " & quoted form of POSIX path of destination & mkdirParams
display dialog "Your folders are done." buttons {"OK"}
```

Comment: See my second comment to the OP.

Comment: @user3439894 I know it's not the most efficient solution  I added a compromise.